# Create a start and stop date based on location from multiple rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
  MRN    LocationGUID   transferdate
    123    209300610    2016-05-16 00:51:00.000
    123    209100610    2016-05-17 13:58:32.000
    123    148900610    2016-05-20 23:55:28.000
    456    853698742    2016-05-01 08:15:00.000
    456    951357782    2016-05-03 14:32:28.000
```

My table looks like the one above, what I need to do is make it look like the below

```
MRN locationGUID  Transferdate                   Transferstop
123 209300610      2016-05-16 00:51:00.000       2016-05-17 13:58:32.000
123 209100610      2016-05-17 13:58:32.000       2016-05-20 23:55:28.000
123 148900610      2016-05-20 23:55:28.000       GETDATE()
456 853698742      2016-05-01 08:15:00.000       2016-05-03 14:32:28.000
```

Comment: How do you compute for `TranserStop`? Also, what version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I need to keep the time with the date.

Comment: Transerstop is the next locationGUID

Comment: I should have been a little more specific, there will be a unique indicator in front of the locationGUID, like a 123 for all 3 rows

Comment: Please edit your question and complete the details. Provide workable sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on SQL Server 2012+, then you can use [**`LEAD`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) window function:

```
SELECT LocationGUID, 
       CAST(Transferdate AS DATE) AS Transferdate, 
       CAST(COALESCE(LEAD(transferdate) OVER 
                     (ORDER BY transferdate), GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS Transferstop
FROM mytable
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98050/1)

**Note:** If you want to keep time then you can simply omit the `CAST` to `DATE` from the query.